# Finding a proper t-distribution given a constraint about the weight of its tail

Tags: normal-distribution, t-distribution, fat-tails

I wish to find the parameter $\nu>2$ for the student t-distribution such that the following constraint will hold: if $F_T$ is the CDF of that distribution and $F_N$ is the CDF of the normal distribution, then
$$\frac{F_T\left(-2\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}}\right)}{F_N(-2)}=c$$
for some pre-determined $c$.

The motivation is as follows: the ratio between the CDFs is some measurement of weight of tails. Since both distributions are symmetric, it should suffice to check the left tail. The choice of $-2$ is arbitrary, and due to previous analysis I've made. The reason $\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}}$ appears there is since this is the standard deviation of the t-distribution with parameter $\nu$, and the "definition" of a left tail here is whatever appears beyond 2 standard deviations.

I assume one may not hope to find $\nu$ for any given $c$. For $c=1$ the answer must be $\nu=\infty$; I believe it is impossible for $c<1$. I don't know about any upper bound, but I believe there is such. Currently I am interested in $c$ values which are in the interval $(1,2)$.

Comment: To understand what's going on, I just plotted the function in $\nu$ in 'R': 'plot(nu, pt(-2*sqrt(nu/(nu-2)), df = nu)/pnorm(-2))', which seemed to be stable at around $\nu = 8$. The maximum was around 1.09, so I guess you should be able to obtain the $\nu$ numerically for all c in (1, 1.09).

Comment: Thanks for the effort! So you think I should not expect a solution for $c=1.5$, say?